# How to toggle the Firefox JSON Viewer dark-mode?

Tags: json, firefox, browser, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

How can I turn it dark-mode? I already set the Firefox theme to dark but it didn't change...

Answer (score 18):

Your question bring me to the answer! I was troubling with the same and recently discovered how to do it.

## OS

- Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (64-bits)

If you have another OS on which it also worked, please add a comment below and I will add it (or add it yourself editing this answer).

## Browser details

- Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu
- Version 78.0.1 (64-bit)

## Steps to reproduce

1. Press F12 (open Developer Tools)
2. Press F1 (or go to the "..." button at the top right corner and then press "Settings")
3. In **Themes** select **Dark**
4. Done

Comment: If this solves your question, please mark it as the answer :)

Comment: It's quite an odd choice from Firefox to derive JSON document's color scheme from dev tools theme. Home screen for example uses the browser theme, and I think every other page should too.